# JQuery Packery Center Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope, packery

In my [JQuery Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/) app I want to center my items inside the container element. I use the following structure:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item w2">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

I used JQuery Isotope before where I could apply a fix to center the items. My problem is when you have only few items they do not get fixed.

1. Here is one [solution](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dbpzu) which I modified from [this](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/nfkth) one from the plugin's author:

Only the container is centered but not the items inside.

[image]

2. [Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxsil) is a second solution:

[image]

What I want to have is the following. The container width must be bounded by the items such that the container appears centered as well as the items. How can I get that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Centered Masonry? 
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/centered-masonry.html